# Why am i getting invalid syntax using curl in pycharm?

Tags: curl, syntax

I am brand new at Python an i'm trying to followa basic programming cours from ciso/github. i am following some instructons verbatim, literally a cu n paste from some sample code, yet i still get syntax errors . can somebody telly me what is going wrong please?` her is my code

```
curl -k -x "https://10.85.116.30:443/restconf/data/Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/logging/monitor/severity" \
-H 'Accept: application/yang-data+json' \
-u 'admin:admin'
```

```
  File "<input>", line 1
    curl -k -x "https://10.85.116.30:443/restconf/data/Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/logging/monitor/severity" \
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
            ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote a bash script. Not a python. Hence the syntax error.
curl is a CLI program.
Take a look on how to run CMD/CLI commands through python. Or use the ‘requests’ module within python to send an HTTP request.

Request module - https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Executing CLI in Python -  [How to execute a program or call a system command from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command-from-python)

Comment: Ok that makes sense and thank you. i am using Pycharm as an IDE, Can i run it from anywhere in there? All i can see apart from the python window is terminal window which just looks like windows cmd

Can i run the curl from within pycharm anywhere?

Comment: BTW - if this answer is correct feel free to accept it as the correct answer (: